# Hierarchical dynamic loaded components with children distributed along dynamic named slots

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs-slots

We're creating an app where the interface is dynamically mounted based on a JSON returned by an API. It looks like this:

```json
{
  "path": "Container",
  "children": [
    {
      "slot": "default",
      "path": "Banner",
      "props": {
        "items": [ "image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg" ]
      }
    },

    {
      "slot": "header",
      "path": "Flex",
      "props": {
        "flow": "row"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "slot": "default",
          "path": "Icon",
          "props": {
            "name": "mdi-forum"
          }
        },

        {
          "slot": "default",
          "text": "Example of title"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So I created a dynamic `ComponentLoader` with a `computed` doing a dynamic `import`, then I also inject more dynamic component loaders recursively as needed, using a `v-for` through the `children` list:

```html
<template>
  <component v-if="component" :is="component" v-bind="$attrs">
    <template v-for="(child, i) of children">
      <ComponentLoader
        v-if="child.path"
        v-bind="child.props"
        :key="`${child.path}-${i}`"
        :path="child.path"
        :children="child.children"
      />
      <template v-else>{{ child.text || '' }}</template>
    </template>
  </component>
</template>

<script>
import Error from '~/components/ComponentLoaderError.vue'

export default {
  name: 'ComponentLoader',
  components: { Error },
  props: {
    path: { type: String, required: true },
    children: { type: Array, default: () => [] },
  },
  computed: {
    component() {
      if (!this.path) return null
      return () => import(`~/components/${this.path}`).then((m) => m || m.default).catch(() => Error)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

It's almost working, but all children gone injected to the default slot of each loaded component, which makes all sense since I'm not informing the desired slot during the loop through the children.

Inspired [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57156772/424498), I added a `v-slot` bind on the `<template>` with the `v-for`, using [Dynamic Slot Names](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Dynamic-Slot-Names) to inject on the right slot based in the `child.slot` property already received from the JSON:

```html
<template v-for="(child, i) of children" #[child.slot]>
```

For nodes with only one child to be distributed on each slot, it's working as expected. But when I have more children to be distributed in the same slot (like the last children array in that JSON), only the last child is injected, overriding others before.

So, **how to inject many children to dynamic named slots inside a loop?**

Comment: But how can I inject more than one child inside a dynamic named slot, since it overrides the previous children and stays only the last one when the `#[child.slot]` is put along with the `v-for`?

Comment: My renderer is already capable of handling an array, correctly showing how many dynamic child components I load. But when I use `#[child.slot]` to distribute each child to the right slot, it's like the `v-for` is ignored.